# C++ Binary >> no operator found which takes a right hand operand type of const char error

Tags: c++

im trying to learn c++ and can't figure out the reason for this error it seems to match up with my other cout lines that aren't getting any errors

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number = 42;
    int guess;
    bool notguessed = true;
    while (notguessed);

    cout << "Guess my number";
    cin  >> "Guess";
    if (guess == number)
    {
        cout << "You got it" << endl;
        notguessed = false;
    }
    if (guess < number)
    {
        cout << "To low try again" << endl;
    }
    if (guess > number)
    {
        cout << "To high try again" << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (notguessed);` will block everything below ...

Comment: To be more explicit, don't place `;` after `while` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program has two errors - Compilation error and Logical Error. 
**Compilation Error -** Consider this code segment -
 
`cin  >> "Guess";`
Here you trying to give a value to a constant. What you intended to do is - 
`cin>>guess`
**Logical Error -** When you make above changes your code will compile fine but will not work as you want it to, this is because of the following line -
 
`while (notguessed);`
The above while loop will run infinitely as `notguessed` is `true` and no where in the loop its value is modified.
Change that to -

```
 while (notguessed){

    cout << "Guess my number";
    cin  >> guess;
    if (guess == number)
    {
        cout << "You got it" << endl;
        notguessed = false;
    }
    else if (guess < number)
    {
        cout << "Too low try again" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Too high try again" << endl;
    }
}
```

**Note -** I converted your simple `if`statements to `if else if`, this is to avoid unecessary checking of other `if`s when one `if` already evaluated to `true`.
There is an alternative approach to the above where you are not required to use the variable `notguessed`, by using `break` keyword -

```
  while (true){

    cout << "Guess my number";
    cin  >> guess;
    if (guess == number)
    {
        cout << "You got it" << endl;
        break;
    }
    else if (guess < number)
    {
        cout << "Too low try again" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Too high try again" << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :-

```
# your code goes here
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number = 42;
    int guess;
    bool notguessed = true;
    cout << "Guess my number";
    while (notguessed)
    {
        cin  >> guess;
        if (guess == number)
        {
            cout << "You got it" << endl;
            notguessed = false;
        }
        if (guess < number)
        {
            cout << "To low try again" << endl;
        }
        if (guess > number)
        {
            cout << "To high try again" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You were trying to input a string "Guess". Change that to cin>>guess.
And change the while loop semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

```
cin  >> "Guess";
```

should be

```
cin >> guess;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make change in line 10
while loop with ; 
remove ;
provide some 
while(condition){// do code }

Make change in line 13

```
you mistakenly ""
it means string
you need variable
String guess;
 cin  >> guess;
```